# Short script to create a table in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm having some problem creating a short sql script for MariaDB.

> 1. Why are both messages printed out although they are separated by a ELSE?
> 2. Is the DELIMITER realy needed? I've found mixed opinions

Here the script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;

USE mydb;

DELIMITER ;;

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                    FROM    information_schema.Tables
                    WHERE   table_schema = 'mydb'
                            AND TABLE_NAME = 'users' )  THEN
        \! echo "The table users already exists";
    ELSE 
        CREATE TABLE users(
            id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            last_login TIMESTAMP
        ) ENGINE=INNODB;
        \! echo "The table users has been created";
    END IF;

;; DELIMITER ;
```

And here the error:

```
MariaDB [mydb]> source create-1.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.000 sec)

Database changed
The table users already exists
The table users has been created
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7 in file: 'create-1.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE 
        CREATE TABLE users(
            id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     ...' at line 6
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7 in file: 'create-1.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
MariaDB [mydb]>
```

Comment: mydb ?- I hope you aren't trying to mess with the existing mysql system database mydb...

Comment: there is no echo in mysql and # is used to comment out a line of code (or --space)

Comment: In mysql if statement cannot be used outside of a stored procedure, so this question does not apply to mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon I didn't know about it; I just replaced my database name with "mydb"

Comment: @Shadow your comment is really useful, thank you

Comment: @P.Salmon now I understand also the second point, thus to make what I want I need some external scripting, like a Python script

Comment: @Shadow the question is about MariaDB. They added a feature to [use compound statements outside of stored routines](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-compound-statements-outside-of-stored-programs/). Yet another example of MariaDB != MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin the question was tagged with both mysql and mariadb tags. I pointed out that the script cannot work under mysql as is and removed the mysql tag. Left the comment to the OP why I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IF NOT  EXISTS and avoid IF ELSE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  users(
        id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        last_login TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: I know the option (I used it for the database), but I would like to write messages

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your script like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;

USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_login TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=INNODB;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

With this script you will get a message if the table already exists

```
+-------+------+--------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                        |
+-------+------+--------------------------------+
| Note  | 1050 | Table 'users' already exists   |
+-------+------+--------------------------------+
```

and no message if the table is created